# updating Mapbox LineString in realtime

Tags: android, mapbox

What is the best method to update `LineString` source in real time? I've tried removing the source from the mapstyle & re-adding however Mapbox SDK complains saying source is in use.

i'm simply updating the map when the user progresses along the route.

```
style.removeSource("line-source") //complains that it is in use
style.addSource(GeoJsonSource("line-source",
                FeatureCollection.fromFeatures
                (listOf(Feature.fromGeometry(LineString.fromLngLats(asPoints)))))) //fails as already exists
```

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to update the *FeatureCollection* of the source, without removing the source it self:

1. Get the source with from the *Mapbox* instance `GeoJsonSource source = mapboxMap.getSourceAs("line-source");`
2. Give the source the new `LineString` this way:

```
source.setGeoJson(
    FeatureCollection.fromFeature(
        Feature.fromGeometry(LineString.fromLngLats(asPoints))
    )
);
```